# Connecting to remote host that has same IP network as local network fails

Tags: wireguard

I have a home automation host installed at a remote location which I access through WireGuard VPN. The router at the remote location uses 192.168.1.x, which is the same network as my home router. I can access this host fine through mobile data, but when I try to access the host from my home network over the Internet it fails. I speculate it is searching for the host in my home network since it uses the same IP network (the IP address the host is using is not used in my home network though).

I could change one of my networks to 192.168.2.x, but not sure how to do this or if there's a simpler method to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 choices here:

1. The simplest is to ensure that both locations do not have overlapping  subnets, so that basic routing will continue to work normally.
2. You set up routing on the wireguard client to totally cut you off from the local network when connected. This would basically be set up a single host route to the local gateway, then drop the default route and set it to the other end of the vpn tunnel.

Option 1 the best case is that you just change the subnet range in the router and reboot all your devices on that network. This assumes everything is DHCP.

Option 2 depends on how you are running wireguard and what OS, but iirc the wireguard client on Linux uses rules based routing so it gets complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went with option 1. I actually didn't know that my router had a very straightforward method with clear labels to change the subnet range. Thought it would be more complicated than this. Cheers!